# A Euclidean domain in which radix expansion is not possible

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, euclidean-domain

It is well known that given two nonconstant polynomials $f,g\in F[x]$ where $F$ is a field, there are unique polynomials $r_0,\dots ,r_n$ such that

$$f=r_n g^n +\dots+r_1 g +r_0,$$

where $\deg r_i <\deg g$ for all $i$. In other words, the radix expansion is possible in the ring $F[x]$. The proof is by induction on $\deg f$, similar to the existence of radix expansion for integers, and it uses the fact that in the division algorithm of polynomials the degree of the quotient is less than the degree of the dividend, when the degree of the divisor is bigger than zero.

But the above fact is not true in every Euclidean domain. For example in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ we have

$$1=(1-i)(1+i)-1.$$

And the norm (degree) of the quotient $1-i$ is bigger than the norm of the dividend $1$. Hence the above proof does not work in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

**So my question is**, is there a Euclidean domain $R$ in which there are two nonzero nonunit elements $a,b$ such that there does **NOT** exist elements $r_0,\dots ,r_n \in R$ with $\deg r_i <\deg b$ so that

$$a=r_n b^n +\dots+r_1 b +r_0.$$

Note that I am not asking about the nonuniqueness of the coefficients of the expansion, since counterexamples to uniqueness are easy to build. Rather, my question is about the nonexistence of the expansion.